# How can I use PowerShell to edit hyperlinks in a Word document?

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I am in the process of converting a series of 3500 html documents to Word for a documentation repository. We've run into a problem where some hyperlinks are broken on the back end of the conversion for no apparent reason. I want to generate a list of filenames and the links contained in each to see if I can spot any patterns and adjust my conversion program accordingly. Unfortunately, searches that include PowerShell and hyperlinks lead to a lot of items about how to ADD hyperlinks using Powershell, and none of the situations have been applicable to my needs.

Using [this link](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/02/22/fix-spaces-in-hyperlinks-that-exist-in-a-word-document/) and [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8355e885-d664-4db5-9ff2-0958bd2438a7/test-ms-word-documents-hyperlinks-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) as my starting point with this code....

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$document = $word.documents.open("C:\users\administrator\desktop\TEST.docx") 
$document.Hyperlinks 
([uri]"http://domain.com/This is a bad link").AbsoluteUri 
$hyperlinks = @($document.Hyperlinks) 
$hyperlinks | ForEach {
    If ($_.Address -match "\s") {
        $newURI = ([uri]$_.address).AbsoluteUri
        Write-Verbose ("Updating {0} to {1}" -f $_.Address,$newURI) -Verbose
        $_.address = $newURI
    }
}
$document.save()
$word.quit()
```

I've been trying to craft something that will meet my needs. I can duplicate the above script's results, but have not been able to get a successful run iterating through all the documents in a directory with a `ForEach` command. I'm trying to change all links from html to doc, but the second I insert this code:

```
If ($.Address. -match ".\.doc") {
    $newExt = ".doc" ;
    $newURI = ([uri]$$_.address).BaseName.$newExt.
```

I get out of bounds and command failure errors at runtime. [This Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/24/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-hyperlinks-to-a-word-document.aspx) helped, and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355266/how-to-programmatically-edit-all-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document) answers my question for VBA/VBScript...but not PowerShell. Does anyone have a Powershell solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone had asked a similar question, for Excel a while ago:
[Excel & Powershell: Bulk Find and replace URL's used in formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537464/excel-powershell-bulk-find-and-replace-urls-used-in-formulas/18537735#18537735)

So, once you have hyperlinks you could simply replace the .html to .doc using -replace. For example:

```
$hyperlinks | % {$_.TextToDisplay = $_.address= $_.address -replace '.html','.doc'}
```

Note that If you do not change TextToDisplay, hyperlink address will change but you will still be seeing the old values.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the following:

```
If ($.Address. -match ".\.doc") {
             ^
    $newExt = ".doc" ;
    $newURI = ([uri]$$_.address).BaseName.$newExt.
                     ^                           ^
```

Why not rewrite it into something like this (you'll need to find the right types like Hyperlink yourself)

```
$toChange = $document.Hyperlinks | ? { $_.address.endswith('.doc') } | % { $_.address = $_.address.replace('.doc', '.html') }
```