# Powershell & Excel : Find and Replace portion of a formula not fully working

Tags: excel, powershell

Using an example from another thread ([Excel & Powershell: Bulk Find and replace URL's used in formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537464/excel-powershell-bulk-find-and-replace-urls-used-in-formulas)) I'm trying to build a Find & Replace process.

The issue that I am having is it's not "replacing" my string.  Meaning, it's not even recognizing the replacement in the variable.

Here is my code:

```
$path = "C:\TEMP"
$excelSheets = Get-Childitem -Path $path -Include *.xlsm -Recurse
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false

foreach($excelSheet in $excelSheets)
{
 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelSheet)
 "There are $($workbook.Sheets.count) sheets in $excelSheet"

For($i = 1 ; $i -le 12; $i++)
 {
  $worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("P$i")
  "`tLooking for links on $($worksheet.name) worksheet"
  $rowMax = ($worksheet.usedRange.rows).count
  $columnMax = ($worksheet.usedRange.columns).count
  For($row = 1 ; $row -le $rowMax ; $row ++)
  {
   For($column = 1 ; $column -le $columnMax ; $column ++)
    { 
     [string]$formula = $workSheet.cells.item($row,$column).formula

     $changed = $formula -replace 'A$3:$A$104','$A$2:$A$104'
     if ($formula -ne $changed) {
        $workSheet.cells.item($row,$column).formula = $changed
     }


    } #end for $column
   } #end for $row
  $worksheet = $rowmax = $columnMax = $row = $column = $formula = $null
 } #end for

 ## The line below is actually cause file to be not saved when closing it as you are telling excel, hey you are saved.
 ## $workbook.saved = $true
 ## I would use this:
    $workbook.save()
    $orkbook.close()
} #end foreach


 $excel.quit()
 $excel = $null
 [gc]::collect()
 [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

It seems to be the $ symbols messing things up but I need to search those exact string. I even tried to escape the $ symbols with ` but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did the original you copied from work? If so, highlight what you changed.

Comment: No it did not work, hence this post.   I'm referring to the -replace portion specifically. 

-replace 'A$3:$A$104','$A$2:$A$104' is not working.  But I just replace a single letter or number it works. But I need to check the full string inclusive of the special characters.

Comment: Try `$formula -replace [regex]::Escape('A$3:$A$104'), '$A$2:$A$104'`

Comment: It has a selected answer so I assume the original did work…

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, operator `-replace` uses Regex and because there are characters in your string to replace that have special meaning in regex (see the table below) you need to escape these with a backslash.

You can do this manually of course: change `'A$3:$A$104'` into `'A\$3:\$A\$104'`, but by far the easiest way is to use the `[regex]` static method `.Escape()` for this:

```
$changed = $formula -replace [regex]::Escape('A$3:$A$104'),'$A$2:$A$104'
```

Another way here would be to use the string method `.Replace()` which doesn't use regex, BUT is **case-sensitive**:

```
$changed = $formula.Replace('A$3:$A$104','$A$2:$A$104')
```

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |